# How to display specific JSON data using Javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON data :

```
{
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResult": {
    "lines": [
      {
        "boundingBox": [
          2,
          52,
          65,
          46,
          69,
          89,
          7,
          95
        ],
        "text": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract the text from this JSON data. How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem faced?

Comment: is it just `myJson.recognitionResult.lines.text` ?

Comment: @Yanis-git not really...  lines is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
var myJSON = {
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResult": {
    "lines": [
      {
        "boundingBox": [
          2,
          52,
          65,
          46,
          69,
          89,
          7,
          95
        ],
        "text": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy",
        }
  ]
}
}

var text = myJSON.recognitionResult.lines[0].text;
console.log(text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. God bless

Comment: @JayaramRamanarayanan, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
var status = myJSON.status;
alert( status );

var text = myJSON.recognitionResult.lines[0].text;
alert( text );
```

Comment: Thank you, solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to make your code consider the dynamic behaviour. What if your `lines` array have multiple objects? So, I recommend to use a loop for this case, although there is even one object.

```js
var jsonData = {
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResult": {
    "lines": [
      {
        "boundingBox": [
          2,
          52,
          65,
          46,
          69,
          89,
          7,
          95
        ],
        "text": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy"
      },
       {
        "boundingBox": [
          2,
          52,
          65,
          95
        ],
        "text": "fox jumps over the lazy"
      }
    ]
  }
};
jsonData.recognitionResult.lines.forEach(function(line){
  console.log(line.text);
});
```